# Can i host a shiny app on a windows machine?

Tags: r, shiny

I've registered for the beta hosting.
I've tried to follow the directions for creating the shinyapps/myapp folder on my widnows machine.
I can run shiny apps locally.
I've installed the node.js program shiny requires but I can get the config file?
I think my error message requires python?
Is there an easier way to host the shiny app on a windows machine?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

https://github.com/leondutoit/shiny-server-on-ubuntu

deployment is fairly easy. Too bad, the author is not very responsive.

Comment: Yes, same as your noted above, but I found it easier for other people to stay updated.

Answer (score 29):

a bit of a late answer: **it is possible to host a shiny app on Windows**.

use the following run.R script below, start it as a job on the windows machine.
Do make sure that the port (below 1234) is open in the local firewall.

Enjoy!

```
require(shiny)
folder_address = 'H:/path to app'

x <- system("ipconfig", intern=TRUE)
z <- x[grep("IPv4", x)]
ip <- gsub(".*? ([[:digit:]])", "\\1", z)
print(paste0("the Shiny Web application runs on: http://", ip, ":1234/"))

runApp(folder_address, launch.browser=FALSE, port = 1234, host = ip)
```

Comment: how do you keep it running even after a user x's out from the browser?

Comment: This is terrible for hosting multiple apps. Need something like shiny proxy that only opens the app when someone tries to access it.

Comment: It actually works, surprisingly well. We run dozens of apps on it for years before buying RStudio

Comment: @clnreanu I wonder if this solution works with simultaneous users who run the same functions by applying different filters etc?

Comment: @maydin yes it works, each user sees his/her own instance

Comment: I wonder if this solution works with huge numbers of simultaneous users(20+)

Comment: I don't know why but simply setting `host = "0.0.0.0"` works for me just as well as the solution that fetches the ip from within R. `0.0.0.0` seems to get automatically translated to my host computer's IP4 address as I can connect to the app from a different computer via `http://[ip of my host computer]:1234`.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Shiny website](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server):

> You'll need a Linux server, with the following prerequisites
>   installed:
>
> Node.js 0.8.16 or later For Ubuntu, we have found these instructions
>   to work well. For Red Hat/CentOS, we recommend installing from source.
>   R 2.15 or later Shiny R package, installed into the machine-wide site
>   library. This is one easy way to do that: sudo su - -c "R -e
>   \"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""

You cannot natively host Shiny apps on a Windows machine right now. Running a virtual machine with Linux might be a good alternative.

Comment: What about through a virtual machine?

Comment: If you install Linux on the virtual machine than you can install Shiny Server on that machine.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I have been able to set up Shiny Server on a Linux VM. By using a bridged network I can also access the Shiny application on my Windows Server (also a VM currently) and host machine (Windows 10). On my Windows Server I have setup an IIS web server. Do you have an idea how I can route my application to run as part of a website hosted on an IIS web server? I am tied to finding ways to do this due to IT infrastructure, and I want to find ways to incorporate R and R Shiny in our workflow and make them available for co-workers but also external parties.