# downloadHandler() problems: MacOS fine but no result with Windows

Tags: r, shiny

I am working with R and shiny on my MacBook. The application works fine. Part of the application is the download of results. For this I have included a downloadHandler(). This works on my Mac fine, but when I copy the application on the Windows computer of a friend - nothing happens. The file dialog opens. You can select a filename - but no file is stored. I am using the internal browser of Rstudio for this. Both on Windows and MacOS.

Does anyone has an idea?

I copy the downloadHandler here:

```
output$result.download <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() { 
    paste('result-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='') 
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.table(result, file, sep=';', dec=',', na='', row.names=F)
  }
)
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with this:?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052441/can-i-host-a-shiny-app-on-a-windows-machine

Comment: Dont know - thanks for the hint. Will look into this. The rest of the application works just fine. It is only the downloadHandler() that is not working.

Comment: Probably cross-posted at https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/shiny-discuss/c8fa3b37-2132-47cc-8faa-1f29d66474c3%40googlegroups.com