# Host shiny app on Windows

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyproxy

First of all my question is very related to

[How to host Shiny apps on windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848995/how-to-host-shiny-apps-on-windows-server)

But, it seems that i need some more reputation to comment in other posts....

My problem/question: I have a shiny app that i want to deploy and make available for people in my department. The paid version of shinyapps.io is not an option for now at least, so i am looking for alternatives. I am working on Windows and this is a problem from what i understand in order to host my own server. I tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44584982/8805826), but i get the following error:

```
"Error in makeTcpServer(host, port, appwrapper$onHeaders, appwrapper$onBodyData,  : Expecting a single value: [type=character; extent=5].
```

Also, another solution is shinyproxy. But it is rather complicated to set it up and i didn't find anywhere how to do that on Windows 10 Home edition ( so no Hyper-V availability...). If you are aware of this, please let me know!

I would appreciate any help to figure it out!

Thanks,
Giannis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the regular expression finds 2 values for IPv4 and is storing them in the z value.

Run this and check how many Ip-adresses it returns:

```
x <- system("ipconfig", intern=TRUE)
z <- x[grep("IPv4", x)]
z
```

If the print statement looks like this, it wont work:

> print(z)
>
> [1](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/) "   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : xxx.xxx.x.xxx"   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : x.x.x.x"

You will have to decide on one of them. In this example i am taking the second Ip-Adress ( z[2] ): I also changed "launch.browser = FALSE" to TRUE, so that the shiny-App opens in the browser.

```
ip <- gsub(".*? ([[:digit:]])", "\\1", z[2])
print(paste0("the Shiny Web application runs on: http://", ip, ":1234/"))
runApp(folder_address, launch.browser=TRUE, port = 1234, host = ip)
```

Do you have a local Linux Server in your department? You could easily upload it there, using the Open Source Version of [Shiny Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/)

Comment: Yes! It seems that this was the problem after all! By selecting one of them works fine! I don't know actually.Maybe i have to talk with the IT department...If this is not a possibility, i don't know what's next...Thanks for you help ! :)